# How can someone say I'm fantastic the first time we meet?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass

Normally, after you've met a person at least twice you can select to say they're fantastic. They won't receive this rating until the next time you meet, which means that nobody should be able to say I'm fantastic until we've met at least 3 times.

However, there have been Miis that have said I'm fantastic on the second time we meet and today one said it when we've never met before. How can this happen?

Comment: At a thought, maybe you were still in range when they said you were fantastic?

Comment: Have you considered you're just that fantastic?

Comment: Being still in range might explain it for the second time, but not the first.

Answer (score 2):

Did you find those Miis from **SpotPass** and not classic StreetPass? Because in an hotspot you can receive people's Mii but that person may not "meet" your Mii at the same time. I know this because a friend of mine has met my Mii through SpotPass but I haven't met his one that day.

Probably that person have met you more than 3 times (giving you the "Fantastic"), and the first time you've received its Mii in your Plaza you've actually got the "Fantastic".

Comment: I guess it's possible, it doesn't tell me how I got the Mii.

Answer (score 0):

I have a theoretical answer that hinges on a technical detail that I cannot confirm is true, but it's something.

Here's the deal. If A and B meet, and B then changes their StreetPass Mii to C, then the next time they meet, A will meet C for the first time while B/C will meet A for the second time. This should trigger the "am I fantastic?" on B/C's system while leaving A in the dark.

So, this is what I think could happen:

- A meets B. B meets A.
- A meets B again. B meets A again. Both elect to send a fantastic the next time the two meet.
- B changes to C.
- C meets A. C sends "I think A is fantastic".
- A meets C. A receives a fantastic despite never having seen C before. A's "I think B is fantastic" is never sent (as A doesn't meet B)...until C changes back to B, probably.

Note that this working depends on the following detail being true: once a fantastic is fired, it no longer matters which Mii sent it, only which Mii it's targetted at.